# Posting image from .NET to Facebook wall using the Graph API

Tags: c#, .net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the Facebooks Javascript API to develop an application that will need to be able to post an image to a users wall.
That part of the app needs to be server-side as far as I can tell, since it needs to post the image data as "multipart/form-data".

Note: It's not the simple version using "post", but the real "photos" method.

http://graph.facebook.com/me/photos

I think I'm facing two problems, a .NET and a Facebook problem:

**Facebook problem:** I'm not quite sure if all parameters should be send as multipart/form-data (including the access_token and message). The only code example there is uses the cUrl util/application.

**.NET problem:** I have never issued multipart/form-data requests from .NET , and I'm not sure if .NET automatically creates the mime-parts, or if I have to encode the parameters in some special way.

It's a bit hard to debug, since the only error response I get from the Graph API is "400 - bad request".
Below is the code as it looked when I decided to write this question (yes, it's a bit verbose :-)

The ultimate answer would of course be a sample snippet posting an image from .NET, but I can settle for less.

```
string username = null;
string password = null;
int timeout = 5000;
string requestCharset = "UTF-8";
string responseCharset = "UTF-8";
string parameters = "";
string responseContent = "";

string finishedUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos";

parameters = "access_token=" + facebookAccessToken + "&message=This+is+an+image";
HttpWebRequest request = null;
request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(finishedUrl);
request.Method = "POST";
request.KeepAlive = false;
//application/x-www-form-urlencoded | multipart/form-data
request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data";
request.Timeout = timeout;
request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
if (username != null && username != "" && password != null && password != "")
{
    request.PreAuthenticate = true;
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password).GetCredential(new Uri(finishedUrl), "Basic");
}
//write parameters to request body
Stream requestBodyStream = request.GetRequestStream();
Encoding requestParameterEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(requestCharset);
byte[] parametersForBody = requestParameterEncoding.GetBytes(parameters);
requestBodyStream.Write(parametersForBody, 0, parametersForBody.Length);
/*
This wont work
byte[] startParm = requestParameterEncoding.GetBytes("&source=");
requestBodyStream.Write(startParm, 0, startParm.Length);
byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath("images/sample.jpg"));
requestBodyStream.Write( fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length );
*/
requestBodyStream.Close();

HttpWebResponse response = null;
Stream receiveStream = null;
StreamReader readStream = null;
Encoding responseEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(responseCharset);
try 
{
    response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
    receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    readStream = new StreamReader( receiveStream, responseEncoding );
    responseContent = readStream.ReadToEnd();
}
finally 
{
    if (receiveStream != null)
    {
        receiveStream.Close();
    }
    if (readStream != null)
    {
        readStream.Close();
    }
    if (response != null)
    {
        response.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a sample of how to upload binary data. But an uploading to /me/photos won't publish the image into wall :( The image saving into your app's album. I'm stuck on how to announce it in the feed. Yet another way is to post an image into "Wall Album", by URL=="**graph.facebook.com/%wall-album-id%/photos**". But didn't found any way to create sucha album (user creates it when uploading an image via the site).

```
{
    string boundary = "---------------------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");
    uploadRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos");
    uploadRequest.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
    uploadRequest.Method = "POST";
    uploadRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; Windows NT)";
    uploadRequest.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
    uploadRequest.KeepAlive = false;

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    string formdataTemplate = "--{0}\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{1}\"\r\n\r\n{2}\r\n";
    sb.AppendFormat(formdataTemplate, boundary, "access_token", PercentEncode(facebookAccessToken));
    sb.AppendFormat(formdataTemplate, boundary, "message", PercentEncode("This is an image"));

    string headerTemplate = "--{0}\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{1}\"; filename=\"{2}\"\r\nContent-Type: {3}\r\n\r\n";
    sb.AppendFormat(headerTemplate, boundary, "source", "file.png", @"application/octet-stream");

    string formString = sb.ToString();
    byte[] formBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(formString);
    byte[] trailingBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("\r\n--" + boundary + "--\r\n");

    long imageLength = imageMemoryStream.Length;
    long contentLength = formBytes.Length + imageLength + trailingBytes.Length;
    uploadRequest.ContentLength = contentLength;

    uploadRequest.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;
    Stream strm_out = uploadRequest.GetRequestStream();

    strm_out.Write(formBytes, 0, formBytes.Length);

    byte[] buffer = new Byte[checked((uint)Math.Min(4096, (int)imageLength))];
    int bytesRead = 0;
    int bytesTotal = 0;
    imageMemoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    while ((bytesRead = imageMemoryStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
    {
        strm_out.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead); bytesTotal += bytesRead;
        gui.OnUploadProgress(this, (int)(bytesTotal * 100 / imageLength));
    }

    strm_out.Write(trailingBytes, 0, trailingBytes.Length);

    strm_out.Close();

    HttpWebResponse wresp = uploadRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @fltz. Managed to get it working by adapting your example (some of the vars where declared outside the scope of the snippet).

Comment: Do your application posts an image to the wall or just upload it into application's album? In my tests there was no sight of uploaded image on the wall/feed.

Comment: I haven't gotten around to it yet. So far I only see it on the wall when the default album for the application is created. But according to [this post](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1626/how-to-post-to-a-users-wall-upload-photos-and-add-a-like-button-from-your-iphone-app) it should be possible.

Comment: I am answering here for question "how to publish it photo on own's timeline". See whenever some photos get published to timeline, It follows 2 steps
1. Adding a photo to album "Timeline_Photos"
2. Publishing a new post(feed) with photo(above) id, so that it can be displayed as a thumbnail. 


While working with Graph API, we also have to follow same steps
1. POST /version/me/photos <Provide here caption and URl/Source>
2. POST /version/me/feed <Provider here Object_Attachment which will be photo id received in above step>

Answer (score 3):

Cleaned up class method using @fitz's code. Pass in a byte array or a file path for the image. Pass in an album id if uploading to an existing album.

```
public string UploadPhoto(string album_id, string message, string filename, Byte[] bytes, string Token)
{
    // Create Boundary
    string boundary = "---------------------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");

    // Create Path
    string Path = @"https://graph.facebook.com/";
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(album_id))
    {
        Path += album_id + "/";
    }
    Path += "photos";

    // Create HttpWebRequest
    HttpWebRequest uploadRequest;
    uploadRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(Path);
    uploadRequest.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
    uploadRequest.Method = "POST";
    uploadRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; Windows NT)";
    uploadRequest.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
    uploadRequest.KeepAlive = false;

    // New String Builder
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    // Add Form Data
    string formdataTemplate = "--{0}\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{1}\"\r\n\r\n{2}\r\n";

    // Access Token
    sb.AppendFormat(formdataTemplate, boundary, "access_token", HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlEncode(Token));

    // Message
    sb.AppendFormat(formdataTemplate, boundary, "message", message);

    // Header
    string headerTemplate = "--{0}\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{1}\"; filename=\"{2}\"\r\nContent-Type: {3}\r\n\r\n";
    sb.AppendFormat(headerTemplate, boundary, "source", filename, @"application/octet-stream");

    // File
    string formString = sb.ToString();
    byte[] formBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(formString);
    byte[] trailingBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("\r\n--" + boundary + "--\r\n");
    byte[] image;
    if (bytes == null)
    {
        image = File.ReadAllBytes(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(filename));
    }
    else
    {
        image = bytes; 
    }

    // Memory Stream
    MemoryStream imageMemoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    imageMemoryStream.Write(image, 0, image.Length);

    // Set Content Length
    long imageLength = imageMemoryStream.Length;
    long contentLength = formBytes.Length + imageLength + trailingBytes.Length;
    uploadRequest.ContentLength = contentLength;

    // Get Request Stream
    uploadRequest.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;
    Stream strm_out = uploadRequest.GetRequestStream();

    // Write to Stream
    strm_out.Write(formBytes, 0, formBytes.Length);
    byte[] buffer = new Byte[checked((uint)Math.Min(4096, (int)imageLength))];
    int bytesRead = 0;
    int bytesTotal = 0;
    imageMemoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    while ((bytesRead = imageMemoryStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
    {
        strm_out.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead); bytesTotal += bytesRead;
    }
    strm_out.Write(trailingBytes, 0, trailingBytes.Length);

    // Close Stream
    strm_out.Close();

    // Get Web Response
    HttpWebResponse response = uploadRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

    // Create Stream Reader
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

    // Return
    return reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to construct the multipart/form-data yourself using byte arrays.
Anyway I've already done this. You can check out the Facebook Graph Toolkit at http://computerbeacon.net/ . I'll update the toolkit to version 0.8 in a few days, which will include this "post photo to facebook wall" function as well as other new features and updates.

Comment: Thanks - Looking forward to taking it for a spin.

Comment: This site can’t be reached

Answer (score 1):

I was able to post pictures using [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/):

```
// url example: https://graph.facebook.com/you/photos?access_token=YOUR_TOKEN
request.AddFile("source", imageAsByteArray, openFileDialog1.SafeFileName, getMimeType(Path.GetExtension(openFileDialog1.FileName)));
request.addParameter("message", "your photos text here");
```

[User API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#photos) or [Page API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#photos) for posting photos

[How to convert Image to Byte Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17352061/fastest-way-to-convert-image-to-byte-array)

Note: I was passing an empty string as the mime type and facebook was smart enough to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe useful

```
        [TestMethod]
        [DeploymentItem(@".\resources\velas_navidad.gif", @".\")]
        public void Post_to_photos()
        {
            var ImagePath = "velas_navidad.gif";
            Assert.IsTrue(File.Exists(ImagePath));

            var client = new FacebookClient(AccessToken);
            dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();

            parameters.message = "Picture_Caption";
            parameters.subject = "test 7979";
            parameters.source = new FacebookMediaObject
{
    ContentType = "image/gif",
    FileName = Path.GetFileName(ImagePath)
}.SetValue(File.ReadAllBytes(ImagePath));

            //// Post the image/picture to User wall
            dynamic result = client.Post("me/photos", parameters);
            //// Post the image/picture to the Page's Wall Photo album
            //fb.Post("/368396933231381/", parameters); //368396933231381 is Album id for that page.

            Thread.Sleep(15000);
            client.Delete(result.id);
        }
```

Reference: 
[Making Requests](http://blog.prabir.me/posts/facebook-csharp-sdk-making-requests)