# How to upload image on facebook using graph api?

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I want to upload an image on user profile. I have an image in `Bitmap` form. I am using this code...

```
        Bitmap bit = new Bitmap("E:\\abc.jpg");
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

        bit.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

        byte[] buffer = ms.ToArray();


        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?access_token=" + acc_token);

        req.Method = "POST";
        req.ContentLength = buffer.Length;
        //req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        req.ContentType = "image/jpeg";                       

        Stream rq_strm = req.GetRequestStream();
        rq_strm.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        rq_strm.Close();

        HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();     //got error here
        Response.Write("RESPONSE: " + res.StatusDescription);
```

I got the error `The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.` Where am I wrong ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4898950/posting-image-from-net-to-facebook-wall-using-the-graph-api

Answer (score 0):

Basically, this means that the server didn't recognize your request. Typically for an API, this means that the API couldn't decipher something, or it was missing an important feature. In this case, it determined that you included no `source` tag. Typically, this is sent via an HTML form with the `<input type='file'>` tag. The way to emulate this is rather complex, but  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/567460/544198) will point you in the right direction.