# Save and retrieve image (binary) from SQL Server using Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, bitmap, binary

I am trying to save a bitmap image to database

```
Bitmap map = new Bitmap(pictureBoxMetroMap.Size.Width, pictureBoxMetroMap.Size.Height);
```

I created a column `imgcontent` in the database with datatype `binary` but my problem is how can I convert this `bitmap` (map) to binary data?

And how can I retrieve data from database?

I googled it and I found something like this but it didn't work:

```
byte[] arr;
ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
arr = (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(map, typeof(byte[]));
```

Comment: @JensB thank you but you didn't use EF!!Am i right ?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Convert the image to a `byte[]`  and store that in the database.

---

Add this column to your model:

```
public byte[] Content { get; set; }
```

Then convert your image to a byte array and store that like you would any other data:

```
public byte[] ImageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image imageIn)
{
    using(var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        imageIn.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
    
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}

public Image ByteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
     using(var ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn))
     {
         var returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);

         return returnImage;
     }
}
```

Source: [Fastest way to convert Image to Byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17352061/fastest-way-to-convert-image-to-byte-array)

```
var image = new ImageEntity()
{
   Content = ImageToByteArray(image)
};

_context.Images.Add(image);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

When you want to get the image back, get the byte array from the database and use the `ByteArrayToImage` and do what you wish with the `Image`

This stops working when the `byte[]` gets to big. It will work for files under 100Mb

Comment: What if I want to save a file whixh exceeds 100MB? How do I tweak the code?

Comment: @bangbang Then I would personally think about storing the file on disk and saving the path to the file in the database instead.

Comment: however if you still want to save it in DB, use varbinary(max). limit 2GB.

Comment: @AdeelShekhani The problem for me was not that the database would be unable to store it but that EF would time out or take a very long time trying to send it to the database.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using this extension library if you want clean and efficient use of memory for bigger files.
This library stores files in smaller chunks.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Files.EntityFrameworkCore.Extensions

If support file Create, Delete & Get.

```
public class UserImage : IFileEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid FileId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string MimeType { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset TimeStamp { get; set; }
    public Guid? NextId { get; set; }
    public int ChunkBytesLength { get; set; }
    public long TotalBytesLength { get; set; }
    public byte[] Data { get; set; }
}

//Save file chunks from stream to database, you can also save from filePath
var fileDetails = await _context.SaveFileAsync<UserImage>(file.OpenReadStream(), file.FileName, file.ContentType);

//Create Stream and download file chunks from database into this stream.
var stream = new MemoryStream();
await _context.DownloadFileToStreamAsync<UserImage>(id, stream);
```