# C# : how to get value from specific column from SQL Server and store into variable

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I want to ask how to store the full name (from database @3) of the user into the variable `fname`.

```
SqlDataReader rdr = cm.ExecuteReader();
string sql = "Select * from Login where Username like'" + txtUser.Text + "'and password like'" + txtPass.Text + "'";

cm = new SqlCommand(sql, cn);
dr = cm.ExecuteReader();

dr.Read();

if (dr.HasRows)
{
    cn.Close();
    AutoClosingMessageBox.Show("Access Granted. Welcome " + txtUser.Text + "!", "Successfully Login.", 400);

    cn.Open();
    UserID = cm.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

    //fname = ;
    Form1 frmMain = new Form1();
    frmMain.pass(UserID);
    frmMain.Show();
    this.Hide();
    //...
}
```

My database : @0 = ID, @1 = Username, @2 = Password, @3 = full name, @4 = binary image. I can't post photo :( >

If anyone also knows how to convert the binary into a picture, that would help me a lot thanks.

Comment: but @3 is password as per the details in question.

Comment: my my bad it should start at @0..

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   while (dr.Read())
    {
           string userid=dr["sql_column_name"].ToString();
           //rest of the code...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select ID from Login where Username like
```

use ID instead of *.

you can read binary  as array of byte :byte[],
if you saves image file in your database use system.io.streamwriter but if you saved the image you can use bitmap class

Answer (score 0):

At first, it's better to use `=` operator for checking username and password in queries, instead of `like`.

To have the fullname field value, you can simply use the `dr` property as follows:

```
var fullname = dr["fullname"];
```

or any other field value:

```
var userID = dr["ID"];
```

do these things before `cn.close()`. I've no idea why you close the connection and open it again after a `MessageBox`!
another issue with your code is you have executed the command already, there is no need to run in again with `ExecuteScalar()`.

Your code could be so:

```
string sql = string.format("SELECT * FROM Login WHERE Username='{0}' AND Password='{1}'", txtUser.Text, txtPass.Text);
cm = new SqlCommand(sql, cn);
var dr = cm.ExecuteReader();
if (dr.Read()) // Read() returns TRUE if there are records to read, or FALSE if there is nothing
{
    fname = dr["fullname"];
    UserID = dr["ID"].ToString();

    AutoClosingMessageBox.Show("Access Granted. Welcome " + txtUser.Text + "!", "Successfully Login.", 400);

    Form1 frmMain = new Form1();
    frmMain.pass(UserID);
    frmMain.Show();
    this.Hide();
    //...
}
```

---

for your second question, you can convert the binary field to image and vice versa using these methods as [@JensB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25400555/save-and-retrieve-image-binary-from-sql-server-using-entity-framework-6) says:

```
public byte[] imageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image imageIn)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    imageIn.Save(ms,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
    return  ms.ToArray();
}

public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
     MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
     Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
     return returnImage;
}
```

Usage:

```
var theImage = byteArrayToImage((byte[])reader.Items["imageBinary"]);
```