# How can i map a byte[] value to SQL type Image?

Tags: c#, sql

I have the following interface:

```
IEnumerator<SqlDataRecord> IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord>.GetEnumerator() 
{
    var SQLRow = new SqlDataRecord(
        new SqlMetaData("id", SqlDbType.BigInt),
        new SqlMetaData("image", SqlDbType.Image));

    foreach (ImageModel item in this)
    {
        SQLRow.SetSqlInt64(0, item.Id);
        // here is the problem (this is a byte[] variable)
        SQLRow.SetSqlByte(1, item.Image); 

        yield return SQLRow;
    }
}
```

So how can i map the `byte[]` to `Image`? Or maybe i can store the image in a different way?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put `new SqlDataRecord(..)` inside `foreach` statement, otherwise it will return the same object all the time and just overrides the values. Not sure how do you use it but it might be a problem.

To set the value use `SQLRow.SetSqlBytes(1, new  SqlBytes(...));`
or  `SQLRow.SetSqlBinary(...) or SQLRow.SetBytes(...)`

It is better if you use `varbinary(max)` or `varbinary(YOUR MAX LENGTH)` type for storing your data as the `image` type is obsolete in MS SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the byte array as it is in SQL Server.This way its easier to retrieve back in your application.

Comment: OK. How about performance issues. If i save it as a `NVARCHAR(MAX)` vs `Image` what is the downside?

Comment: Using byte[] will yield performance gain over nvarchar(max)..nvarchar is meant for string with support for different encodings.For your case you can refer to the post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25400555/save-and-retrieve-image-binary-from-sql-server-using-entity-framework-6