# Convert R plot to binary/byte array

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, r, ggplot2

I've created a plot in R using ggplot2 (base plot works here too). I'd like to "convert" it to binary form and save it in my SQL Server database as a `varbinary(max)`. Is this clear? Is this possible?

As an analog, in C#, I can accomplish this by creating a Bitmap image, saving it to a `MemoryStream` object, converting it via `ToArray()`, then saving it in SQL Server as `SqlDbType.Binary`. (i.e. this process: [Save and retrieve image (binary) from SQL Server using Entity Framework 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25400555/save-and-retrieve-image-binary-from-sql-server-using-entity-framework-6))

So can I do something like this in R?

Comment: All the graphics devices seem to require a file path to render a lot and cannot write directly to connections. You'd have to write it to disk, then read the bytes back into R.