# Store files in database using Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

How to store files in a SQL Server database using Entity Framework Core (Code-First) in an ASP.NET Core app?

I have tried using `Filestream` but unfortunately I get this error:

> Cannot call Property for the property 'Avatar' on entity type 'UserProfile' because it is configured as a navigation property. Property can only be used to configure scalar properties

Here's the code:

```
public class UserProfile : BaseEntity {
    public FileStream Avatar { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public Sex Sex { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<Email> Emails { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
}
```

And mapping:

```
public class UserProfileMap {
    public UserProfileMap(EntityTypeBuilder<UserProfile> entityBuilder) {
        entityBuilder.HasKey(e => e.ID);
        entityBuilder.Property(e => e.Avatar);
        entityBuilder.Property(e => e.FirstName);
        entityBuilder.Property(e => e.LastName);
        entityBuilder.Property(e => e.DateOfBirth);
        entityBuilder.Property(e => e.Sex);
        entityBuilder.Property(e => e.Address);
        entityBuilder.Property(e => e.PhoneNumber);
        entityBuilder.HasMany(e => e.Emails).WithOne(u => u.UserProfile).HasForeignKey(x => x.UserProfileID);
    }
}
```

What do I do? Thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can convert the file bytes to a byte array.

```
public byte[] Avatar { get; set; }
```

Examine the accepted answer in the analogous approach for EF6:
[Save and retrieve image (binary) from SQL Server using Entity Framework 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25400555/save-and-retrieve-image-binary-from-sql-server-using-entity-framework-6)

Comment: But is there a way to store them using Filestream?

Comment: The entity classes are simple POCO classes (plain old CLR objects).

Supported data types are the elementary .NET data types (String, DateTime, Boolean, Byte, Byte[], Int16, Int32, Int64, Single, Double, Decimal and System.Guid). 

By convention, the database provider selects a data type based on the CLR type of the property. It also takes into account other metadata, such as the configured Maximum Length, whether the property is part of a primary key, etc. (cf. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/data-types). IMO we cannot use FileStream as property type.

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming that you are trying to use the windows filestream for sql server, which is [not yet supported by .NET Core](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/4573). You have to store the file as a byte array as already said (which will convert to varbinary(max) in sql server) and copy the file content over when uploading using a memory-stream for instance.

Answer (score 2):

By Ef core, you can't store file in your database until now, so you can:

1. store the result of reading files as byte[]
   like this :

```
public byte[] Avatar { get; set; }
```

```
var avatar =  File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
```

2.use your machine as a file server and store the path of your file in database :

```
public string Avatar { get; set; }
```

In my Opinion the second way is better and i always use this pattern but it depends on your machine's H.D.D and the amount of files you want to store.

Answer (score 0):

There is a much better way of storing files with EntityFrameworkCore, this library make it much easier https://www.nuget.org/packages/Files.EntityFrameworkCore.Extensions

Its stores files in small chunks so you don't have to worry about using too much memory during file upload or downloading.

Examples are also available on [Github repopsitory](https://github.com/SitholeWB/Files.EntityFrameworkCore.Extensions)

```
public class UserImage : IFileEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid FileId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string MimeType { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset TimeStamp { get; set; }
    public Guid? NextId { get; set; }
    public int ChunkBytesLength { get; set; }
    public long TotalBytesLength { get; set; }
    public byte[] Data { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<FilesExtensionsResponse>> UploadFile([FromForm] IFormFile file)
{
     if (file.Length > 0)
     {
         var fileDetails = await _context.SaveFileAsync<UserImage>(file.OpenReadStream(), file.FileName, file.ContentType);
         return Ok(fileDetails);
     }
     else
     {
         return BadRequest("File is required.");
     }
}
[HttpGet("{id}/download")]
public async Task<IActionResult> DownLoadFile(Guid id)
{
    var fileDetails = await _context.GetFileInfoAsync<UserImage>(id);
    var stream = new MemoryStream();
    await _context.DownloadFileToStreamAsync<UserImage>(id, stream);
    return File(stream, fileDetails.MimeType, fileDetails.Name);
}
// And more methods are available
```