# Using FileStream in SQL with code first in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core

I need to create a table and use `FileStream` in that table. In the SQL Server table, I need to use this column:

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable
(
    FileID  UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL ROWGUIDCOL UNIQUE DEFAULT(NEWID()),
    Pic     VARBINARY(MAX) FILESTREAM NULL
)
```

Now in EF Core code-first how can I create this column?

Comment: This is a question about _generating_ the column, right? Not _using_ the column?

Comment: @gunr2171 i need to add tow colmun in model with codefirst

Comment: Repeating what you said in your post when I ask a clarification question doesn't answer the question.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6924857/1043380) is an answer from a previous version of EF. I doubt the functionally has changed.

Comment: @gunr2171 `generation`

Answer (score 0):

See this [solution](http://ignoringthevoices.blogspot.com/2014/01/working-with-entity-framework-code.html), in which the author shows how to modify the `Up()` and `Down()` methods in an EF migration (i.e. the initial migration) to add a `FILESTREAM` column, and also how to perform the read/write operations.

He's using EF6, but I would think that the same could be done with EF Core.

Answer (score -1):

In EF core , you could not use `FileStream` to save file to database.

Instead, you need to convert the file to `byte[]`(which will convert to varbinary(max) in sql server) and copy the file content over when uploading using a memory-stream for instance.

Model:

```
public byte[] Picture { get; set; }
```

Convert file to byte array:

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
  file.CopyTo(ms);
  byte[] fileBytes = ms.ToArray();
  string s = Convert.ToBase64String(fileBytes);
  // act on the Base64 data
}
```

Refer to

[Store files in database using Entity Framework Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48845318/store-files-in-database-using-entity-framework-core)

[How to convert a file into byte array in memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36432028/how-to-convert-a-file-into-byte-array-in-memory)

Comment: so from your answer it means that EF Core cannot be used to store a file as a Filestream but instead only as varbinary?

Comment: Response was not on the subject it was regarding mssql FileStream, not .net FileStream