# Argument Exception while converting byte array to image

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I convert `Image` to `byte[]` using this code (`Form.cs`):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1 fom = new Form1();

    ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
    byte[] imgArray = (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(fom.panel1.BackgroundImage, typeof(byte[]));

    ImageData img = new ImageData
    {
        ClassName = textBox1.Text,
        Password = textBox2.Text,
        Image = imgArray,
    };

    using (BoardDatabaseEntities dc = new BoardDatabaseEntities())
    {
        dc.ImageDatas.Add(img);
        dc.SaveChanges();
        MessageBox.Show("Saved into database");      
    }

    this.Close();
}
```

Then, I am trying to convert it back to `Image`::

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (BoardDatabaseEntities dc = new BoardDatabaseEntities())
    {
        var v = dc.ImageDatas.Where(a => a.ClassName.Equals(TextBox3.Text) && a.Password.Equals(TextBox4.Text)).FirstOrDefault();
        if (v != null)
        {
            byte[] byt = v.Image;

            ImageConverter ic = new ImageConverter();
            System.Drawing.Image img = (System.Drawing.Image)ic.ConvertFrom(byt);

            String name = v.ClassName;

            try
            {
                var ratio = (double)100 / img.Height;
                int imageHeight = (int)(img.Height * ratio);
                int imageWidth = (int)(img.Width * ratio);

                System.Drawing.Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort dCallback = new System.Drawing.Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort(ThumbnailCallback);
                System.Drawing.Image thumbnailImg = img.GetThumbnailImage(imageWidth, imageHeight, dCallback, IntPtr.Zero);

                thumbnailImg.Save(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Thumbnail"), name), ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                thumbnailImg.Dispose();

                //Here Code for Get Uploaded Images
                PopulateImage();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

It is giving me an `ArgumentException` Error in line:

```
System.Drawing.Image img = (System.Drawing.Image)ic.ConvertFrom(byt);
```

It says, parameter is invalid.

Comment: What Namespace does `ImageConverter` come from?

Comment: You should debug and make sure that the byte[] byt = v.Image has data.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17352061/fastest-way-to-convert-image-to-byte-array for alternative approaches.

Comment: @Steve from System.Drawing