# What is the relationship between image file formats and image "encoder name"?

Tags: python, image, encoding, python-imaging-library

I am using the Python Imaging Library to turn a photo into a byte array. This can be done by

```
im = Image.open("hello.jpg")
myImageArray = im.tobytes()
```

From the documentation, the `tobytes` function is defined by

```
def tobytes(self, encoder_name="raw", *args):
        """
        Return image as a bytes object

        :param encoder_name: What encoder to use.  The default is to
                             use the standard "raw" encoder.
        :param args: Extra arguments to the encoder.
        :rtype: A bytes object.
        """
```

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17352107/1795801) answer, Jon Skeet says "In order to convert an image to a byte array you have to specify an image format".  **Is the encoder the image format?**

When `tobytes` defaults to raw, does this mean it is encoded as .raw and would need to be decoded as a .raw to be interpreted correctly, or do they mean something else by raw? Would it be nonsensical to try to encode a JPEG file as a bitmap byte array (i.e.

```
im = Image.open("hello.jpg")
myImageArray = im.tobytes('not jpg encoder')
```

Comment: The other question is for C# although the same concept holds; however this question is particular to a library. There is probably a list of supported formats (and encoder name that support them).