# Covert xamarin.image into base 64 format

Tags: image, xamarin, xamarin.forms, signaturepad

I need to Convert a xamarin forms image into a base64 format, Can anyone help me with this?

This is how i've being trying to do it, but it doesent work.

```
var inputStream = signatureImage.Source.GetValue(UriImageSource.UriProperty);

            //Getting Stream as a Memorystream
            var signatureMemoryStream = inputStream as MemoryStream;

            if (signatureMemoryStream == null)
            {
                signatureMemoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                inputStream.CopyTo(signatureMemoryStream);
            }

            //Adding memorystream into a byte array
            var byteArray = signatureMemoryStream.ToArray();

            //Converting byte array into Base64 string
            base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray);
```

"signatureImage" is the image name.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33947138/convert-image-into-byte-array-in-xamarin-forms

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but how can i pass a file path? The image is in XAML where the image source is being set from data taken from a signature pad.

Answer (score 6):

Once you get your `file` path , you can use the following code that worked for me.

```
var stream = file.GetStream();
var bytes = new byte [stream.Length];
await stream.ReadAsync(bytes, 0, (int)stream.Length);
string base64 = System.Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
```

I found it [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/27743/image-to-base64-conversion)

Answer (score 0):

Image is just a control in Xamarin forms to display the image. 
It is not something from which you can get your image byte array out.

You will be better of using the [Media Plugin](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugin.Media) and save it to disk. Then load it via memory stream and convert.

You can also use [FFImageLoading](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.FFImageLoading.Forms/). It has 2 methods which can be of use for you :

1. [GetImageAsJpgAsync(int quality = 90, int desiredWidth = 0, int desiredHeight = 0)](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/wiki/Xamarin.Forms-API#getimageasjpgasyncint-quality--90-int-desiredwidth--0-int-desiredheight--0)
2. [GetImageAsPngAsync(int desiredWidth = 0, int desiredHeight = 0)](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/wiki/Xamarin.Forms-API#getimageaspngasyncint-desiredwidth--0-int-desiredheight--0)

The SO question - [Convert Image into byte array in Xamarin.Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33947138/convert-image-into-byte-array-in-xamarin-forms) shows how to do it in Platform specific code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33966589/1155650).

The forum thread ([Convert Image to byte[]](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/46010/convert-image-to-byte)) has a good discussion on why you can't get it from the control.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, But isnt there any other way that i could get the image from the XAML and and convert it to a byte array other than saving and getting it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as below as well

```
var base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(file.Path))
```