# Convert Image to ByteArray in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

May I know how to convert image (take from folder/take from Camera) to Byte Array?
& also convert Byte Array to image?

**Take Photo From Camera**

```
 async void TakePhoto()
        {

            try
            {
                var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
                {
                    Directory = "Sample",
                    Name = "test.jpg",
                    //SaveToAlbum = saveToGallery.IsToggled
                });

                if (file == null)
                    return;

                //  await DisplayAlert("File Location", (saveToGallery.IsToggled ? file.AlbumPath : file.Path), "OK");

                img.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
                {
                    var stream = file.GetStream();
                    file.Dispose();
                    return stream;
                });
            }
            catch 
            {

            }
        }
```

**Take Photo From Folder**

```
async void FromFolder()
        {

            try
            {
                Stream stream = null;
                var file = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync().ConfigureAwait(true);


                if (file == null)
                    return;

                stream = file.GetStream();
                file.Dispose();

                img.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);

            }
            catch 
            {

            }
        }
```

I dont know where are the location of Image, and where to get the image.

I'm trying to save image into Azure database. But i'm facing problem to convert MediaFile into Byte[]. I'm using Xam.Plugin.Medie ( http://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugin.Media ) to access camera and gallery. Please kindly guide me how to convert MedieFile into Byte[]. Thank you.
Any sample source code for references

Comment: Better to avoid putting images. Use code fragments instead.

Comment: file.Path will give you the path to the image

Comment: @Jason How to convert to byte array? Any references?

Comment: File.ReadAllBytes()

Comment: @Jason Any sample source code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Image into byte array in Xamarin.Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33947138/convert-image-into-byte-array-in-xamarin-forms)