# Convert image to byte array using MemoryStream.GetBuffer via ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, arrays, image-processing

I have a method below to convert a PNG image file (known file size: under 1MB) to a byte array, Response class returns the byte array for a web request for image download.

The problem is ToArray(), which creates another copy in memory. GetBuffer() returns the underlying buffer, which provides better performance.

```
public byte[] imageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image imageIn)
{
    using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
   {
        imageIn.Save(ms,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        return  ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Can anyone provide the code using GetBuffer()?

.NET 4.5, ASP.NET,

[Creating a byte array from a stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221925/creating-a-byte-array-from-a-stream)

[Fastest way to convert Image to Byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17352061/fastest-way-to-convert-image-to-byte-array)

Comment: PNG file is not `System.Drawing.Image` type. Am I missing something? What are you hoping to achieve over all?

Comment: Download an image file from an ASP.net website. Is it what you asked?

Answer (score 0):

You should save the file directly to the output steam of asp.net

```
    public ActionResult DownloadFile()
    {
        Image imageIn = GetImage();

        imageIn.Save(Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Png);

        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
```

Comment: do you dispose the imageIn?

Comment: Depending on who owns the imageIn object, if it's created everytime we call `GetImage()` then you'll need to Dispose of it. However it could be shared within this class then we'd need to implement IDisposable etc.. (however this is just an example)